# WinError 5, When importing openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to import openpyxl in order to start learning it, however whenever I try to import it it spits out this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Py\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 17, in <module>
    from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_workbook
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 31, in <module>
    from openpyxl.packaging.manifest import Manifest
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py", line 42, in <module>
    mimetypes = MimeTypes()
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\mimetypes.py", line 74, in __init__
    init()
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\mimetypes.py", line 368, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\mimetypes.py", line 253, in read_windows_registry
_mimetypes_read_windows_registry(add_type)
```

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

In case it helps here is all the code I used

```
import openpyxl
```

I have tried to:

- Upgrade pip
- Take ownership of AppData\Local\Programs\Python
- Install pydirectory
- Run file as administrator
- Run file from administrator CMD
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling openpyxl

With no impact

Half-Solution.

I found that downgrading from python 3.10.8 to 3.7 removed the error. Everything 3.8 onward crashes. Still have absolutely no clue as to why they crash.

Comment: Hello. Can you please format the output properly either with linebreak or in a code block, use the `{}` button instead.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your pc? Or running it in dockers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reinstalling package will work in your case.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 0):

With the bug report in [Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100256),[Python Discussion1](https://discuss.python.org/t/ensurepip-failing-with-access-is-denied-error-when-attempting-to-read-windows-registry/21482/10?u=ak88) and [Python Discussion2](https://discuss.python.org/t/ensurepip-failing-with-access-is-denied-error-when-attempting-to-read-windows-file/30241/18), this is a "Access Denied" Windows registry opening action executed by standard library "mimetypes" which exists in significant versions(3.10, 3.11, 3.12).

As the issue still exist until the Github Bugreport is closed, the current workaround is to comment on it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34792142)